# How to make a div with contenteditable="true" a text editor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea, text-editor

I want to know how to make:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="text">
</div>
```

Into a **text editor** but when you highlight it **you can make it bold** by using a JavaScript function and a JavaScript function to turn the keyword div into a textarea so **you can edit the HTML code**!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: HTML: [http://pastebin.com/fKWL0Ak8](http://pastebin.com/fKWL0Ak8)
CSS: [http://pastebin.com/dZ2FH02a](http://pastebin.com/dZ2FH02a)
JS: [http://pastebin.com/Qqs8v8Jh](http://pastebin.com/Qqs8v8Jh)

Comment: You may be able to make it work for you using javascript, by getting the element by id value perhaps